# Does millis() conflict with the PWM pins associated with timer 0?

Tags: timers, pwm, millis

I've read that the `millis()` function uses the same timer as a couple of PWM pins.

If you're using those PWM pins, will `millis()` still return the correct value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They do not conflict as `millis()` strictly reads the immediate value in `TCNT0` whereas PWM via timer 0 uses the hardware's ability to compare the value of `TCNT0` with the values in `OCR0x` without affecting the value of any of them.

Comment: `millis()` just uses Timer 0 overflow counts. `micros()` reads the immediate value in `TCNT0`.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to @Ignacio's answer which has directly answered your question. The "conflict" you speak of is in relation to `Timer0`'s prescaler.

For the most part, you can use those pins (incidentally pins 5 and 6 on the UNO) with PWM without an issue, and read the correct value of `millis()` (as well as get the expected delay from `delay`)

Where you run into problems is if you want to change the prescaler (usually to modify the frequency of the PWM signal). If you change this, then you directly affect the calculation and reporting of `millis()` and the length of `delay(x)`.

Comment: You can read your timer's prescaler by the bottom bits of Serial.println(TCCR0A,BIN);  If they are '11' then your prescaler is clk/64.  You could then calculate the factor for modifying millis() and delay().

Comment: That's a very good point and I've always just steered clear of modifying it, but there's no reason if you really want/need to. The other point is that if you've modified it you already know the new prescaler and could in turn write wrappers for `millis ()` or `delay ()` anyway